# Spring security permit all index

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to permit my index site for all and I want other sites to be authenticated. I made my security configuration like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/addPost").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE","ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/profile").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE","ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
    .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity security){
    security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/node_modules/**","/source/**","/style/**");
}
```

and when I try to access my default page, I got this error:

```
    org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")...
    Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error retrieving value for property "principal.authorities" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken (template: "index" - line 33, col 19)
        at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 97 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error retrieving value for property "principal.authorities" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken (template: "index" - line 33, col 19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.authorities' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.authorities' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.AuthUtils.getAuthenticationProperty(AuthUtils.java:137) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 114 common frames omitted

2018-08-07 13:11:43.856 ERROR 16192 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.authorities' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.authorities' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Comment: but in index-page you use `principal.authorities`!

Comment: In my index page I am using: sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" and sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" in order to dynamically load content. Can I use different checks for being authenticated or anonymous to make this index page run?

Comment: do you have `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` dependency?

Comment: moreover I am using sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" and th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/login' ? 'active':''}". yes, I have this dependency.